# MFC - How can I add a spin control to a ribbonbar

Tags: mfc

I'm using a ribbon style application and I can't seem to find a way to add a spin control to my ribbonbar. In the list of controls of my toolbox there seems to be a spinEdit control but when I add it to the ribbon bar it looks like a ribbonEdit control without showing the up and down buttons that are supposed to be embedded with it. It's there a way to enable this control to behave like a spinEdit or does this control not work at all? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call EnableSpinButtons() on the edit control - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb982261.aspx . Instantiate it like this:

```
CMFCRibbonEdit* edit = new CMFCRibbonEdit(ID_SOME_ID, 75);
edit->EnableSpinButtons(10, 20);
pPanel->Add(edit);
```

Comment: mmm..the thing is I'm using the ribbon designer and I can't seem to find the panel's ID in order to add it by code. Do you know how to do it this way?

Comment: Doesn't your version of VS come with samples that show how to access the ribbon programmatically? I assume your wizard-generated code has a place somewhere where it loads the ribbon resource, with some member variable (probably of CMainFrame) that you can access to find the control. I don't have VS2010 or 2012 at hand so I can't tell.

Comment: Never mind, I tested my app on another computers that have windows 7 as well and the spin buttons are visible. It seems my OS is a little screwed up since I'm getting other weird behaviours, I might have to do a full reinstall. Oh well, but thanks anyway!